How keep storage synchronized between clustered web server
I'm working on a cluster of web servers that use local filesystem as storage for media files. These clustered servers are balanced.
The served webpages gets some images or video from this repository, but since servers are clustered I need to keep storage synchronized, an user may upload something from one server and then get it just after from the other server because the loader switched.
What is a common solution for this purpose? Consider that we are talking of few GB, it is not very big.
I already considered to mount a network or cloud share but I will lose the advantage of a cluster and a local resource.
I also considered to use the database (clustered again) and store all files as blob, but I see there is a lot overhead vs using a local FS.
Just to explain, I cannot use cron and rsync because I need an (almost) live synchronization similar to database or amq between many servers.

In a Windows subsystem you would use a clustering file server's role, so multiple server can access the same storage (via iSCSI or other method). Can't tell in linux how on the other side.

Depending on details about your environment, two options jump to my mind:

MinIO is S3-compatible object storage that you can run in a cluster across multiple nodes, and it uses erasure coding, so you can kinda-sorta think of it like spanning a RAID-5 array across multiple machines.
Ceph is a bigger beast to tame, but it can give you a POSIX-compatible file system that essentially replicates in realtime across multiple nodes. It's more similar to what you're describing, like a realtime rsync.

I know you didn't mention it, but I'll also throw out that both of these work well with Kubernetes. They also work well off-Kubernetes, but both have particularly good integration if you're using it.
From what you've said, I'd consider MinIO if you have control over the application (which it sounds like you do?). It's super simple to get up and running, and should be quite familiar for anyone who's used S3, not to mention the comprehensive library support for those APIs. I rolled out my first MinIO deployment a few weeks ago, so I'm certainly no expert, but I've been quite happy with it.
If you don't have control over the application and need a filesystem, then Ceph could make sense. Just know that it will need a particularly strong network connection between your nodes. I've personally played a bit with Rook (a Kubernetes wrapper for Ceph, essentially), and I did get it working without much hassle, but it's definitely got a steeper learning curve. It's very cool, but unless you're looking to get deep into it, my superficial experience tells me I'd rather troubleshoot a production outage of MinIO than Ceph.
